# Problem with simple CNN in Keras, ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to fit a simple CNN on the Fashion MNIST dataset. However, I run into a ValueError. I've browsed the web on this issues and found a lot about changning loss-function and/or activation function on the output layer. But I want to have my label-variable as a one-hot-encoded and have therefore choosed 'sigmoid' and 'categorical_crossentropy'.

Help that could push me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D

(X_train_val, y_train_val), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train_val, 
                                                  y_train_val, 
                                                  test_size=0.15, 
                                                  random_state=42)
X_train = X_train/255
X_val = X_val/255
X_test = X_test/255

y_train_ohe = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_val_ohe = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_val, 10)
y_test_ohe = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,7, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
])



model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_ohe, epochs=2, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `y_val_ohe` for `validation_data` ?

Comment: I completly missed. Thanks!

Comment: Np. Did it resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it did! I was blind!